# Review of Apriori Based Algorithms on MapReduce Framework

Tags: apriori

I am working on Review of Apriori Based Algorithms on MapReduce Framework. I need some information where i can get the dataset that is good and large for performing the Framework .If anyone can share a open dataset available for use.

Thank you